# How can I add my own class name in wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

I was working with a site. The site has 3 div i.e 3 containers. The 2nd container has the colored body, so I want to toggle with the border radius. but the by default class of WordPress are repetitive. So, It is becoming difficult to work only with 2nd container.

So, I am thinking to add my own extra class to the 2nd div. To perform this need help :)
M working with **elementor pro**

Comment: Is the container element added with Elementor? Each of their modules gives you the option of adding a class and/or an id

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared my browser cache and the option of adding own class and Id is now visible in advance tab.